# Prometheus - calculating the percentage increase

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, metrics

I'm very new to using Prometheus metrics and I've been asked to write an alert based on whether a value has increased by a 10% over the last five minutes.

To be more concise, I've to report when my Kafka topic deadletters count increases by 10% within 5 minutes.

I can count the current deadletters on the topic/sub using this query:

```json
count by(topic) (kafka_burrow_topic_partition_offset{topic=~".+__deadletter__.+my-subscription-name.+"})
```

What I now need to do is get the same number from 5 mins ago and then calculate the percentage increase from then and now:

`Percentage Increase = [ (Final Value - Starting Value) / |Starting Value| ] × 100`

Can anyone give me a steer  on how to calculate the percentage difference?

I've seen examples like this but cant get it to work for me:
          `(sum by(topic) (increase(kafka_burrow_topic_partition_offset{topic=~".+__deadletter__.+"}[5m])) > 0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the following query for calculating the value at the moment:

```
count by(topic) (kafka_burrow_topic_partition_offset{topic=~".+__deadletter__.+my-subscription-name.+"})
```

then the value 5 minutes ago can be calculated by adding `offset 5m` to the query:

```
count by(topic) (kafka_burrow_topic_partition_offset{topic=~".+__deadletter__.+my-subscription-name.+"} offset 5m)
```

Note that the `offset` modifier must be put immediately after closing curly brace in the query above. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier) for more details on this.

Given that, the following query would show the percentage increase for the value during the last 5 minutes:

```
(
  count by (topic) (
    kafka_burrow_topic_partition_offset{topic=~".+__deadletter__.+my-subscription-name.+"}
  ) - count by (topic) (
    kafka_burrow_topic_partition_offset{topic=~".+__deadletter__.+my-subscription-name.+"} offset 5m
  )
) / count by (topic) (
  kafka_burrow_topic_partition_offset{topic=~".+__deadletter__.+my-subscription-name.+"} offset 5m
) * 100
```

P.S. Note that the query contains multiple repeated parts. These parts can be simplified to the following [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) query using [with templates](https://play.victoriametrics.com/promql/expand-with-exprs) from VictoriaMetrics:

```
with (
  q = count by (topic) (
    kafka_burrow_topic_partition_offset{topic=~".+__deadletter__.+my-subscription-name.+"}
  )
)
(q - q offset 5m) / (q offset 5m) * 100
```

Comment: Perfect!  I was able to get this working as needed!  Thank you @valyala

Comment: NOTE: Get an error on the "with" statement `Error executing query: 3:6: parse error: unexpected "="
`

Comment: The `with` syntax doesn't work with Prometheus - it works with [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/).